# What would you say is the best current Link Balancer solution out there?

Tags: bonding

Rather than a server load balancer, I may have a need for an actual internet link balancing application that allows me to share incoming and outgoing traffic between 2 or more ISP connections (or even through a single ISP, but with multiple connections from the ISP) that go to moderately high traffic servers that don't yet justify the cost of a full gigabit connection but frequently need more than 100mbit in bursts.

Searching around, I notice a lot more solutions out there than there was only a year ago. But price vs. performance vs. value all seem to be everywhere on the board.

Any recommendations? Feel free to let me know if you need any clarification. I am just looking for some opinions on trusted solutions, and what the cost may be to do it as apposed to going to a gigabit connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love Peplink's ([peplink.com](http://www.peplink.com)) link balancing router.  We tried the Barracuda as we really like their Web and Email appliances, but it was too new and couldn't really handle the advanced situations we needed.  Plus, the peplink has a really slick interface.

Comment: I add a vote for Peplink.  It's very easy to setup and highly configurable.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a great appliance to look at? [Barracuda Networks Link Balancer](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/link_overview.php)

I have used Barracuda Spam and Web filters with great success and I highly recommend them.

Comment: My major reservation with them is their over priced required service plans on top of the hardware investment. Link Balancer investment for my application with them seems to be $8000 minimum with a 250mbit cap.

Answer (score 0):

I heard or link load balancer from radware that does exactly same thing. I tested IPS from radware named DefensePro once and it was good. I attended their meeting after testing DefensePro and there I saw presentation on link load balancer, application load balancer, XML check offloading, etc. devices.

Have a look at their website at [www.radware.com](http://www.radware.com/). I think the name of link load balancer is link proof.

Answer (score 0):

We have looked a lot of appliances and the best one we found that not only provides enterprise class features but also a reasonable price is the EdgePRO from XRoads Networks.

Answer (score 0):

We checked out a bunch including Peplink and Barracuda and were not selected as their feature set was not the greatest.  We settled on [Elfiq](http://www.elfiq.com) which quite frankly delivers what we need and their support team actually responds with answers (unlike some other vendors which shall remain nameless!).  This box also fails to wire should it fail so you don't add a point of failure in your redundancy - kind of important no?